# MongoDB watch() to return JSON

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'm developing a pipeline from MongoDB to AWS S3.
I'm using the Mongo watch() method to stream events from the log (with pymongo).

The problem is that the events returned cannot be converted to JSON, since they hold Mongo objects in the values, like:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5f0c6cf7200000aacdsertee4ac')}
```

Since the value is not in quotes, the string can't be turned into JSON.

Any way to make the watch() method return strings? or another way to tackle this?

Comment: May be this is useful: [MongoDB Extended JSON - ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/index.html#bson.ObjectId) and [Example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/index.html#example).

Comment: Map values to desired types prior to serialization.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I got to:

```
def bson_ser(x):
if isinstance(x, datetime.datetime):
    return x.isoformat()
elif isinstance(x, bson.timestamp.Timestamp):
    return x.as_datetime().isoformat()
elif isinstance(x, bson.objectid.ObjectId):
    return str(x)
else:
    raise TypeError(x)

with db.watch() as stream:
    for event in stream:
        data = json.dumps(event, default=bson_ser)
```